# How do I create while loop in autohotkey that breaks when I press {Ctrl}?

Tags: autohotkey

I have the following while-loop in autohotkey inside a function:

```
foo(){
    counter:=1
    while(counter<10)
    {    
    send, %counter%
    Random, SleepAmount, 2300, 3300
    sleep, 3000
    counter++
    }
}
```

I want the ability to stop the loop by pressing `{Ctrl}`. What's the best way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: Try adding `~Ctrl:: counter := 10`.

Comment: @user3419297 : Sorry, I forgot to mention that this is inside function. I added the information.

Answer (score 2):

Try it this way:

```
F1:: foo()

foo(){
    counter := 1
    while(counter < 10)
    { 
        send, %counter%
        Random, SleepAmount, 23, 33     
        loop 100
        {
            Sleep, %SleepAmount%
            If GetKeyState("Ctrl", "P") 
                return
        }
        counter++
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I did this by creating a 2nd script where pressing Ctrl would set a global variable to 1. In the first script you initially reset this global variable to 0, then within the loop you check this variable. This way you don't need to keep pressing Ctrl until the GetKeyState is executed. Maybe you could use A_PriorHotkey, but then you should not hit any other keys after you triggered the Ctrl.

Comment: @RobertIlbrink : How about sharing your solution in your own answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
~Ctrl::counter := 10
F1:: foo()

foo(){
    global counter:=1
    while(counter<10)
    {    
    send, %counter%
    Random, SleepAmount, 2300, 3300
    sleep, SleepAmount
    counter++
    }
}
```

Comment: Even when your post, answers OP's question. Please provide not only a snippet that works. But explain what's happening, why it does what it should to etc.