# How to determine whether a Window is visible on the screen with AHK?

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I am trying to run this script from here https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/25619-detect-on-screen/, but it does not work if the Window top border is not touching the screen top:

```lisp
^F2::
If ( ID := WinExist("Calculator") ) 
 {
   WinGetPos , X, Y, , , ahk_id %ID%
   If  ( DllCall("WindowFromPoint", Int,X+5, Int,Y+5 ) = ID ) 
       MsgBox, Calculator is ON SCREEN
 }
Return
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As an alternative to checking whether the window is visible, you can compare the window text contents over time and determine whether it should be enough for you.

On this example, I am checking the `Media Player Home Cinema` window playing time to determine whether I should press the `Media Play/Stop` button, or focus on the `Media Player Home Cinema` window and press `Space` (to play/stop it directly):

```lisp
Pause::
window_identifier = ahk_class MediaPlayerClassicW
WinGetTitle, window_title, %window_identifier%

if( !window_title ) {
    Send {Media_Play_Pause}
}
else {
    WinWaitActive, %window_title%, , 0.1
    is_window_focused := true
```

```lisp
    if( ErrorLevel ) {
        ; MsgBox, WinWait timed out.
        is_window_focused := false
    }
    else {
        PlayPauseVideo()
        return
    }

    counter := 5
    first_result := GetRunningWindowText(window_title)

    while( counter > 0) {
        sleep, 200
        counter := counter - 1
        second_result := GetRunningWindowText(window_title)

        if( first_result != second_result ) {
            PlayPauseVideo()
            return
        }
    }

    if( is_window_focused ) {
        PlayPauseVideo()
    }
    else {
        Send {Media_Play_Pause}
    }
}
```

```lisp
GetRunningWindowText(window_title) {
    WinGetText, window_text, %window_title%

    ; FoundPos := RegExMatch(window_text, "O)(?:\d\d:)+(?<frames>\d\d)", first_result)
    FoundPos := RegExMatch(window_text, "O)drawn: (?<frames>\d+)", first_result)

    ; Msgbox % first_result.Count() ": " first_result.Name(1) "=" first_result["frames"]
    return first_result["frames"]
}

PlayPauseVideo() {
    ; Msgbox, It is running video...
    WinActivate, ahk_class MediaPlayerClassicW
    Send {Space}
}
return
```

References:

1. https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegExMatch.htm
2. [How do I create while loop in autohotkey that breaks when I press {Ctrl}?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47954567/how-do-i-create-while-loop-in-autohotkey-that-breaks-when-i-press-ctrl)
3. https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/35905-how-to-get-ahk-to-wait-a-specified-amount-of-time/
4. http://rouge.jneen.net/

---

## Extra

Rewriting the main code in a function for greater generalization/reuse:

```lisp
Pause::CheckForPlayerWindow("ahk_class MediaPlayerClassicW",
        "{Media_Play_Pause}", "{Space}", "false")

^!Left::CheckForPlayerWindow("ahk_class MediaPlayerClassicW", "{Media_Prev}", "^p")
^!Right::CheckForPlayerWindow("ahk_class MediaPlayerClassicW", "{Media_Next}", "^n")


; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55670223/how-to-determine-whether-a-window
CheckForPlayerWindow(window_identifier, media_key, player_key, reactive=true) {
    WinGetTitle, window_title, %window_identifier%

    if( !window_title ) {
        Send % media_key
    }
```

```lisp
    else {
        WinWaitActive, %window_title%, , 0.1
        is_window_focused := true

        if( ErrorLevel ) {
            ; MsgBox, WinWait timed out.
            is_window_focused := false
        }
        else {
            PlayPauseVideo(window_identifier, player_key, reactive)
            return
        }

        counter := 5
        first_result := GetRunningWindowText(window_title)

        while( counter > 0) {
            sleep, 200
            counter := counter - 1
            second_result := GetRunningWindowText(window_title)

            if( first_result != second_result ) {
                PlayPauseVideo(window_identifier, player_key, reactive)
                return
            }
        }

        if( is_window_focused ) {
            PlayPauseVideo(window_identifier, player_key, reactive)
        }
        else {
            Send % media_key
        }
    }
}
```

```lisp
GetRunningWindowText(window_title) {
    WinGetText, window_text, %window_title%

    ; FoundPos := RegExMatch(window_text, "O)(?:\d\d:)+(?<frames>\d\d)", first_result)
    FoundPos := RegExMatch(window_text, "O)drawn: (?<frames>\d+)", first_result)

    ; Msgbox % first_result.Count() ": " first_result.Name(1) "=" first_result["frames"]
    return first_result["frames"]
}

PlayPauseVideo(window_identifier, player_key, reactive=true) {
    ; Msgbox, It is running video...

    if( reactive == true ) {
        WinGetActiveTitle, active_window_title
    }

    WinActivate, %window_identifier%
    SendInput % player_key

    if( reactive == true ) {
        WinActivate, %active_window_title%
    }
}
return
```

New references:

1. https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm
2. https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/77928-ctrl-v-sendinput-v-is-not-working-in-many-applications/
3. https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/148483-how-to-pass-a-key-in-a-function-parameter/
4. https://autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm

Answer (score -1):

It is not working because the function `WindowFromPoint` from Windows API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-windowfrompoint is being incorrectly used.

It takes only 1 parameter, not 2 parameters as are being passed by. This function does the correct conversion from 2 to 1 parameter are you need:

```lisp
WindowFromPoint(x, y)
{
    VarSetCapacity(POINT, 8)
    Numput(x, POINT, 0, "int")
    Numput(y, POINT, 4, "int")
    return DllCall("WindowFromPoint", int64, NumGet(POINT, 0, "int64"))
}
```

Full example:

```lisp
Pause::
window_identifier = ahk_class MediaPlayerClassicW

WinGetTitle, window_title, %window_identifier%
is_visible := IsWindowVisible(window_identifier)

If( is_visible > 0 ) {
    MsgBox, Window %window_title% is visible!
}
else {
    If( is_visible < 0 ) {
        MsgBox, Window %window_identifier% not found!
    } else
    {
        MsgBox, Window %window_title% is NOT visible!
    }
}
```

```lisp
IsWindowVisible(window_name) {
    ID := WinExist(window_name)

    If( ErrorLevel != 0 ) {
        ; MsgBox, Window %window_name% not found!
        return -1
    }

    If( ID > 0 ) {
        WinGetPos, X, Y, , , ahk_id %ID%
        active_window_id_hwnd := WindowFromPoint(X, Y)

        ; MsgBox, %X%, %Y%, %active_window_id_hwnd%
        If( active_window_id_hwnd = ID ) {
            ; MsgBox, Window %window_name% is visible!
            return 1
        }
        else {
            ; MsgBox, Window %window_name% is NOT visible!
            return 0
        }
    }

    ; MsgBox, Window %window_name% not found!
    return -1
}

WindowFromPoint(x, y)
{
    VarSetCapacity(POINT, 8)
    Numput(x, POINT, 0, "int")
    Numput(y, POINT, 4, "int")
    return DllCall("WindowFromPoint", int64, NumGet(POINT, 0, "int64"))
}
Return
```

References:

1. https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/116760-windowfrompoint-broken-in-windows-81/
2. https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/11978-inidelete-set-errorlevel-if-section-or-key-doesnt-exist/